Storing context prior to sleep (PIC)
Wonder if anybody knows the correct C syntax to store context (in my case just one int) before a PIC 24F sleeps and then recover it when woken.
The example code (Microchip app note), which is supposed to store context in DSGPRO, set the DSEN bit and call sleep is -
asm("MOV #0x8000, w2");
    asm("MOV w2, DSCON");
    asm("MOV w2, DSCON");
    asm("PWRAV #0")

My (probably poor) equivalent in C (to store the int in led_step) is
int *a = (int*) 0x8000;
    *a = led_step;
    
    IFS1bits.INT2IF = 0;        //clear interrupt flag.
    INTCON2bits.INT2EP = 1;     //Interrupt iNT2E is on the falling edge
    IPC7bits.INT2IP = 7;        //set highest interrupt priority to INT2
    IEC1bits.INT2IE = 1;        //Enable INT2IE interruption
    CTMUCONbits.CTMUEN = 0;     //Disable CTMU module
    Sleep();                    // sleep();

But this just results in an output toggling whilst in sleep. The sleep / wake functions do work, there's something wrong with variable storage / recovery.

Many compilers have the asm common extension -- see C11 J.5.10

Thanks, unfortunately no longer in MPLABX, I would prefer to stick with that if possible.

In hindsight, the asm sample only sets the DSEN bit in DSCON, there is no example of how you store context / variables in DSGPR0

Which compiler do you use, which don't have an assembler extension?

Ralph you might like to read this document: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-BB433107-FD4E-4D28-BB58-9D4A58955B1A-en-US-6/GUID-7B7547B4-DA4A-47E5-9F82-A1EFD0507331.html

Thanks Mike and pmg, using MPLABX XC16 which doesn't like asm and I prefer to not mix code. Discovered there's something fundamentally wrong with exit from sleep on PIC24, not executing the next commands properly. Never a good example when you need one.

Of course xc16 sipports assembler, Have a look: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002106C.pdf

MPLABX is an IDE not a compiler.  What compiler are you using,?

Are you suggesting that XC16 - Microchip's own compiler does not accept Microchip's own app not code?  Seems unlikely.  Perhaps that is the question you should be asking - clearly an XY problem.

Thanks, but my original working assembler code produced so many errors from XC16, it was easier to convert 100 lines or so to C. The eventual issue was that the next command after sleep is never executed, despite what all the docs say. The wake caused random jumps to various parts of the code and I had to add a service routine.

"working assembler code produced so many errors from XC16" exactly what I said, an X-Y problem.  You are also confusing the question by referring to assembler code causing errors that is clearly not the assembler code exhibited in the question.  You are not helping yourself with such lack of clarity.  If it was "working assembler" what was it previously working on? i.e. what did you use to assemble it previously.  Any errors were likely differing syntax between assemblers and probably easily fixed.

The Microchip code is inline assembly embeddable in C code. It is likely that they have used it exactly because it cannot be done in C code - which will be the case when accessing non memory mapped registers.
If you are using a compiler other than XC16, your compiler's inline assembly syntax may differ, but will certainly support it one way or another.  I think XC16 supports GCC style in-line assembly.
Si the answer is simply to use in-line assembly, either verbatim as provided or adapted for your specific compiler as necessary.

You had to put the assembly part directly into your c-function by using inline assembly.
There is an example here for the xc16 compiler:
void main void
{
    //do C-stuff
    
    // fall into deep sleep
    // Case 1: simplest delay scenario
    //
    asm("bset DSCON, #15");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    asm("pwrsav #0"
 } 


Thanks, but my original working assembler code produced so many errors from XC16, it was easier to convert 100 lines or so to C. The eventual issue was that the next command after sleep is never executed, despite what all the docs say. The wake caused random jumps to various parts of the code and I had to add a service routine.

Only use the four lines of assembly. The rest should be c-code. Where are your error?

@Ralph  If you have fixed the problem you should either close this question if the information provided is insufficient to answer the question, or update the question to provide necessary information (not in comments) and post an answer yourself.  Otherwise others may be working on it unnecessarily, unaware of the missing information or that the issue is resolved.

I have no idea how to close a question, there is only an option to delete it. I will do this later. I apologise for wasting everybody's time.

To close a question just accept an answer, then everyone can see that the question has been answered. You can also upvote the answers you find helpful..

The eventual issue was that the next command after sleep is never executed, despite what all the docs say. The wake caused random jumps to various parts of the code and I had to add a service routine.

Ralph, I can make you an example but it would help to know which PIC24 controller you are using and which mode, sleep or deep sleep. Yes they are VERY different. Getting this controller to sleep and stay in sleep is tricky.

Thanks Dan, though I had to mostly abandon this as I also needed Timer1 to produce a 2 minute wake interrupt whilst in either sleep mode, and that's not possible. I will use conventional sleep (5uA on a PIC24F16KA102) and an external nanopower timer. PIC24F16KA102 has multiple other issues, but that's another story.
